# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to set the icon image like

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
  try {

        Image img=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/logo.png"));
        setIconImage(img);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The code seems to work perfectly after compilation on NetBeans but I get the IllegalArgumentException if I run the jar file from cmd.I don't seem to understand how the image can be visible in first case and not on the other one.

Comment: can you post a stack trace, and an example of how you are running the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen under Windows (case insensitive file system) where loading may succeed for say `Images/Logo.PNG` on the unpacked class path, and will fail when starting from the **jar** (zip Archive), where paths are case-sensitive.

Correcting the case of a file may be cumbersome (version control and such), hence a rename might be more useful.

Remarks:

If the (actual!) class is in package `x.y.z`, the directory path in the jar is `x/y/z/images/logo.png`.

Hence alternatives to consider are non-child class reference and absolute path:

```
    Image img=ImageIO.read(Xyz.class.getResource("images/logo.png"));
    Image img=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/u/v/w/images/logo.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joop Eggen. I just changed logo.png to logo.PNG and it works perfectly fine.